# Disable the audio autoplay policy restriction on mobile Chrome on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I need to be able to autoplay sounds for a specific web application. As the application is being used internally I have access to the devices and would therefore like to turn off the autoplay restriction for audio on mobile chrome for iOS.

Are there any settings for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a policy `AutoplayAllowed` for this purpose: https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoplayAllowed

But it doesn't work anymore on iOS:

> Policy Support on Chrome on iOS is being removed in Chrome 48 as part of Chrome's move to WKWebView where supporting many of the policies was not possible.

Source: https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/ios-mdm-policy-format